# can I clear cache in AFNetworking or NSURL using iOS not code?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have an app that accesses an API. one of the URLs was inadvertently set to a 301 redirect. It has since been fixed, but users who were using the app to access that URL still can't access it. It works if they uninstall and reinstall the app, but there doesn't seem to be any way to clear it. On one device where I was able to reproduce these circumstances, rebooting the device didn't even help. I want to tell my users how to fix the problem without telling them to uninstall the app.

What can I do?

Comment: It's not a strict answer to your question, but you can add a random number to the URL when doing the request: `myapi.com/endpoint?n=34546123123` to avoid hitting the cache.

Comment: unfortunately that requires a code change - which means i'll have to wait for an app to get submitted, approved and the client to update.

Answer (score 0):

if you can change the request code , then use this code before NSURLConnection start

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:RequestUrl];
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you already use [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache] in your appDelegate.m

you can do this:
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

it will clear all URLCache.